# Framer Motion - Context resets when animating between routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I am currently working on a private project for a company, so I cannot reveal the actual code of my application (sorry for that :/), but my issue can be shown with a simple chat application.

## Context

Let's say I have a chat application where there are different chat rooms and a user can enter one of them using a chat room code. This application is built with `React` and uses `react-router` v6.

The part of the application that represents my problem involves four main components: `App`, `ChatLayout`, `ChatJoin`, and `ChatRoom`, as well as two routes: `/chat/join` and `/chat/room`.

`/chat/join` uses the component `ChatJoin`, which allows you to enter the chat room code to enter the chat room.

`/chat/room` uses the component `ChatRoom`, and it is where you chat with the other people present in the chat room.

`App` is the component in charge of the routes.

`ChatLayout` is the component responsible for storing the chat room information in a context (name of chat room, participants, messages sent, etc.) so `ChatJoin` and `ChatRoom` can access this information.

The application was working perfectly until my team decided to improve user experience by implementing page transitions using Framer Motion (evidently, here is where problems began)

## React components and code involved

This is the `App` component, which is in charge of the routes:

```
function App() {
    const location = useLocation();
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
                <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
                    <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />} >
                        { AuthRoutes }
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="chat" element={<ChatLayout />}>
                        <Route path="join" element={<ChatJoin />}>
                        <Route path="room" element={<ChatRoom />}>
                    </Route>
                {/* More routes and layouts... */}
                </Routes>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

This is the `ChatLayout` component:

```
function ChatLayout() {
    const [chatInfo, setChatInfo] = useState({
        // Just some default chat information
        name: 'Just another chat room',
        participants: [
            { id: 'eytjashda', username: 'FooBar 1' },
            { id: 'loasdadjs', username: 'FooBar 2' },
        ],
        messages: [
            { author: 'eytjashda', message: 'Hello everyone' },
            { author: 'loasdadjs', message: 'Hello FooBar 1, How are you?' },
        ]
    });

    return (
        <ChatContext.Provider value={{ chatInfo: chatInfo }}>
            <Outlet />
        </ChatContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

This is the `ChatJoin` component:

```
function ChatJoin() {
    const chatContext = useContext(ChatContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [chatRoomId, setChatRoomId] = useState('');

    function joinChatRoom() {
        socket.emit('user:join_chat', {
            username: username,
            chatRoomId: chatRoomId
        });
    }
    
    // Socket.io events
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('server:join_chat', ({ chatRoomInformation }) => {
            // We set the chat information for chat room to use
            chatContext.setChatInfo(chatRoomInformation);
            // Once we set the chat information, we go to /chat/room to chat with others
            navigate('/chat/room');
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <motion.div
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 3 }}
            className="gcontainer flex-center row"
        >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={event => setUsername(event.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Chat room code" onChange={event => setChatRoomId(event.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={joinChatRoom}>Chat with others!</button>
        </motion.div>
    )
}
```

And finally, this is the `ChatRoom` component:

```
function ChatRoom() {
    const chatContext = useContext(ChatContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    function sendMessage() {
        // Code needed to send a message...
    }
    
    // Socket.io events
    useEffect(() => {
        // Socket communication between client and server...
    }, []);

    return (
        <motion.div
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 3 }}
            className="gcontainer flex-center row"
        >
            {/* Name of the chat room */}
            <h1>{ chatContext.chatInfo.name }</h1>
            {/* Participants */}
            <div>
                {
                    chatContext.chatInfo.participants.map((participant) => {
                        return <div>{ participant.username }</div>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            {/* Messages */}
            <div>
                {
                    chatContext.chatInfo.messages.map((message) => {
                        return <span>{message.author}: {message.message}</span>
                    })
                }
            </div>
            {/* Send message */}
            <input type="text" placeholder="Message..." onChange={event => setMessage(event.target.value)}/>
            <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send message</button>
        </motion.div>
    )
}
```

## Problem

As you can see in the `App` component, all the routes are inside the `AnimatePresence` component, and this makes the animations work as intended, nonetheless, the chat information is lost when navigating from `/chat/join` to `/chat/room`.

For the animations to work, the `Routes` component needs to have `location.pathname` as its key, so when navigating from `/chat/join` to `/chat/room` the whole `Routes` component re-renders, which causes the `ChatLayout` component to re-render, which causes it to override with the default information all the information that the `ChatJoin` component had store inside the context.

## What I have tried

I have tried eliminating the `key` prop of the `Routes` component, which gets the animations to kind of work, as `exit` animations do not work at all (and I want `exit` animations to work as intended, so this is not a viable solution).

I have also tried using the `AnimatePresence` component inside my `ChatLayout` component instead of the `App` component, like this:

`App` component modified for this solution:

```
function App() {
    const location = useLocation();
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            {/* As you can see, the AnimatePresence component is gone */}
            <Routes location={location}>
                <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />} >
                    { AuthRoutes }
                </Route>
                <Route path="chat" element={<ChatLayout />}>
                    <Route path="join" element={<ChatJoin />}>
                    <Route path="room" element={<ChatRoom />}>
                </Route>
            {/* More routes and layouts... */}
            </Routes>
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

And this is the `ChatLayout` component when modified for this solution:

```
function ChatLayout() {
    const location = useLocation();

    const [chatInfo, setChatInfo] = useState({
        // Just some default chat information
        name: 'Just another chat room',
        participants: [
            { id: 'eytjashda', username: 'FooBar 1' },
            { id: 'loasdadjs', username: 'FooBar 2' },
        ],
        messages: [
            { author: 'eytjashda', message: 'Hello everyone' },
            { author: 'loasdadjs', message: 'Hello FooBar 1, How are you?' },
        ]
    });

    return (
        <ChatContext.Provider value={{ chatInfo: chatInfo }}>
            <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
                <Outlet key={location.pathname}/>
            <AnimatePresence />
        </ChatContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Nonetheless, this solution results in the same problem as the first solution, as it gets the animations to work, but `exit` animations do not work at all (and as I said before, I want `exit` animations to work as intended, so this is also not a viable solution).

## What I want

I want the page transition animations to work properly (from their initial to ther exit state) as well as to not lose the information Chat Context is storing from `ChatJoin` so `ChatRoom` can access it.

## What a possible solution cannot entail

- Exit animations not working properly (as I said before)
- Getting rid of the Chat Context or Chat Layout, as they are needed for architectural purposes

## Finally...

I am very sorry for this long and a little specific explanation of my problem, but I really need to solve it and I have tried many ways to do so, but none of them seem to work. If you have made it so far through my question, do you know any solution? In advance, a tons of thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, but I suspect that having a React key on the `Routes` component when routes transition triggers a tearing down and remounting of the sub-ReactTree... which includes the `ChatLayout` component with its `chatInfo` state.

Promote the `ChatContext.Provider` component and `chatInfo` state higher in the ReactTree such that they are unaffected by the route transitions.

Example:

```
const ChatContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [chatInfo, setChatInfo] = useState({
    // Just some default chat information
    name: 'Just another chat room',
    participants: [
      { id: 'eytjashda', username: 'FooBar 1' },
      { id: 'loasdadjs', username: 'FooBar 2' },
    ],
    messages: [
      { author: 'eytjashda', message: 'Hello everyone' },
      { author: 'loasdadjs', message: 'Hello FooBar 1, How are you?' },
    ]
  });

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider value={{ chatInfo }}>
      {children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ChatContextProvider;
```

`ChatLayout` doesn't serve much of any purpose now so can probably be removed, the `path="chat"` route can still serve as a layout route though, *e.g. it renders an `Outlet` by default*.

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <ChatContextProvider> // <-- remains mounted
      <MainLayout>
        <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
          <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route path="auth" element={<AuthLayout />}>
              {authRoutes}
            </Route>
            <Route path="chat">
              <Route path="join" element={<ChatJoin />} />
              <Route path="room" element={<ChatRoom />} />
            </Route>
            {/* More routes and layouts... */}
          </Routes>
        </AnimatePresence>
      </MainLayout>
    </ChatContextProvider>
  );
}
```